# Разбить строку на множество подстрок используя вводимый с консоли символ разделитель C++

Tags: c++, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, как используя вводимый с консоли символ разделитель разбить строку на множество подстрок? У меня пока получается получить строку только первого и последнего совпадения по разделителю, а нужно весь текст разбить.

Код:

```
cout<<"Enter text here: "<<flush;
string text;
getline(cin, text);
string delim;
cout<<"Enter symbol: "<<flush;
cin>>delim;
string::size_type pos = text.find(delim);
string::size_type posl=text.rfind(delim);
string first = text.substr(0, pos);
string second = text.substr(pos+delim.length());
string last = text.substr(posl+delim.length());
const char* cfirst = first.c_str();
const char* csecond = second.c_str();
const char* clast = last.c_str();
cout << cfirst << endl;
cout << csecond << endl;
cout << clast << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача называется split. И по каким то причинам, ее не добавили в явном виде в stl. Но есть вагон решений - https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/ или https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string

Мне понравилось это решение -

```
char sep = ' ';
std::string s="1 This is an example";

for(size_t p=0, q=0; p!=s.npos; p=q)
  std::cout << s.substr(p+(p!=0), (q=s.find(sep, p+1))-p-(p!=0)) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ получения вектора строк, с помощью `std::stringstream`

```
    static std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) 
    {
            std::vector<std::string> elems;
            std::stringstream ss(s);
            std::string item;
            while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
                    elems.push_back(item);
            }
            return elems;
    }
```